# Property could not be set to a byte value you must set the property to a non null of type int32

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, entity-framework-5

Database is in SQL Server 2005 and the datatype of my column in question is defined as `tinyint` (I cannot change this type)

I have created a model having type as `Int32`. In read statement system is throwing this error.

> Property could not be set to a byte value you must set the property to a non null of type int32

I was facing a similar problem for other types, then after checking CLR mapping I corrected them. Now I am facing this problem only in case of `tinyint` and `smallint`.

Answer (score 23):

From the [SQL Server docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(TINYINT_TSQL);k(SQL11.SWB.TSQLRESULTS.F1);k(SQL11.SWB.TSQLQUERY.F1);k(MISCELLANEOUSFILESPROJECT);k(DevLang-TSQL)&rd=true) you can see that `TINYINT` is a 1 byte value which maps into .Net as a `byte` type. `SMALLINT` is 2 bytes which become `Int16` in .Net.

So you need to change your model to use the correct types.

Answer (score 2):

Simply change property data type from complex entity.
In your case change property from int32 to byte .

At least it worked for me.